# Edge detection using Image Morphology

Tags: image-processing

Is it possible to do an edge detection using ONLY opening and closing  operations?

Where:

opening- $X\bullet  B = (X \ominus B) \oplus B$

closing- $X\circ B = (X \oplus B) \ominus B$

(I know we can do it with erosion dilation)

Comment: What do you mean by opening operation?

Comment: @Evil added definitions.